Chroot jail Permission struggels
Whats up.. I'm kinda confused about the permissions
I have a sftp server running with chroot jail for /srv/sftp,
in there is /data with following permissions
drwxr-x---. 5 UserX sftponly 4096 Oct  1 07:37 data

under data are two dirs:
drwxrwx---. 2 UserX gr_user1   4096 Oct  3 16:21 user1

drwxrwx---. 3 UserX gr_user2   4096 Oct  4 13:49 user2

My problem is now that user1 can access the dir of user2, which should not be able as far as the permissions allow.
I hope I made it as clear as possible.
Many thanks
